# How to revert @ManyToOne mapping and make another class an owner of relation

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say that we have two classes:

`Player`

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
public class Player {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
  private Team team;

}
```

and `Team`

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "teams")
public class Team {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @ToString.Exclude
  private Set<Player> players;

}
```

In the above POJO's, Player is the owner of the entity. In this connection, now I can persist `Team` when I am creating `Player` entity but I want to revert this scenario and make `Team` an owner of the relation. Problem is, that when I am reverting that relation I cannot use `mappedBy` by analogy on side `@ManyToOne`. Here comes the question, how to revert this mapping relation and make a `Team` POJO an owner of the relation.

Comment: You can't. In a bidirectional OneToMany, the Many side is always the owning side. That doesn't mean you can't cascade operations on the OneToMany, and thus persist theplayers when you persist the team.

Comment: I believe JB Nizet's is the answer. To add, foreign keys are generated from the Many side

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you so much for an immediate answer. If I understand right,with `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` on @OneToMany side and I will be able to persist team while player creation?

Comment: No. You will persist players when you persist a team. The persist operation cascades from the team to its players.

Comment: @JBNize Ok, thank you so much. Let me sum up. Many sides are always the owner of the relationship. Moreover, we can manipulate their behaviour by using `CascadeType` flags on the second side. For instance, in my scenario, if I will remove `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` from `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)` in Player class and pass it to relation @OneToMany in Team class if I will be persisting Team players will be created either, right?

Answer (score 0):

@JB Nizet is right. For answering your question just move cascade attribute to `Team` and remove it from `Player`. When `Team` has been created, `Player` is going to be created also.

Comment: thank you so much for a response. I will check it a morning. I have one additional question, namely: does `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` usage on both side (@ManyToOne and @OneToMany) is a bad practice? If I understand it, this will lead to the situation that if I will be persisting Team the players will be persisted and vice-versa, right?